# Insert JSON based on Radio Button Selection

Tags: javascript

I have three radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="MIME" value="application/json">JSON
<input type="radio" name="MIME" value="application/xml">XML
<input type="radio" name="MIME" value="text/plain">Plain
```

and a text area

```
<textarea readonly cols="30" style="resize: none;" rows="8" name="urls" id="urls">{"response":{"status":200}}</textarea>
```

Is there an onchange() method I can use to update the textarea to the below on the click on any radio button

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "header": "json" //xml //txt
    }
```

For a select tag ( another requirement that I have ) I parse the json as an obj and I carry out with the implementation but I'm wondering if the same can be done for radio buttons too
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried something for you, with first radio as default selected. try this

```
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <input type="radio" name="MIME" class="radio" value="application/json" checked="checked">JSON
  <input type="radio" name="MIME" class="radio" value="application/xml">XML
  <input type="radio" name="MIME" class="radio" value="text/plain">Plain
</form>

<textarea readonly cols="30"  id='myTextarea' style="resize: none;" rows="8" name="urls" id="urls">
  {"response":{"status":200, "header":application/json}
</textarea>


<script>
var selection = 'application/json'
var rad = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');
var prev = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        console.log(this.value)
        selection = this.value;
        document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = '{"response":{"status":200, "header":' + selection + '}}';
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, I modified it a bit to suit my requirement